# Дописать регуляр

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
$str = 'https://vk.com/id67601378?z=photo67601378_301447204%2Falbum67601378_00%2Frev';
$r = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/vk\.com\/)[a-z0-9\/]+\?z=([a-z0-9_])/','$1$2',$str);
echo $r;

https://vk.com/photo67601378_301447204%2Falbum67601378_00%2Frev
```

как обрезать шнягу после `photo67601378_301447204`

Comment: О, снова ты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, надо добавить в конец ещё одну группу для всего остального, т.е. для всего того что не попадёт в [a-z0-9_], но вы точно уверены что правильно обрезаете? %2F - это просто закодировнный символ, т.е. для строки photo67601378_301447204%2Falbum67601378_00%2Frev надо выполнить url_decode

```
preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/vk\.com\/)[a-z0-9\/]+\?z=([a-z0-9_])(.*)/','$1$2',$str);
```